# Schedule same query for 7 Projects

Tags: google-bigquery

I've created a Query that selects a subset of data from one Projects view and overwrites a table to store this subset of data.

I now need to run that same query on 7 different but equally configured projects, all of which need append their subset of data into a single aggregate dataset.

A big problem I see here is switching from overwrite to append, which adds complexity in figuring out the last time an append worked correctly and avoiding duplicate data.

I'm thinking to create a parameterized query that will take the project ID as an input and am looking to schedule it 7 times with the given project IDs.

However, maybe there's a better solution? My approach doesn't seem to "right". Maybe a sort of subselect / repeat for every parameter value could be used?

Comment: How about using Cloud Scheduler + Cloud Build (define a pipeline with the 7 queries, and thus keeping it simple/clean/neat)?

Comment: How are you running the queries?

Comment: Right now in the WebUi. I’m open for alternatives

Comment: If you use scripting to loop through a list of project-ids, you will not be able to set a destination table (this is a BQ limitation). What do you think about using a script in Python or something like that? Is it a possibility for you?